# jQuery .eq(index) vs [index] if both return an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble distinguishing why exactly one method works and the other one doesn't. I have a workable solution by using .eq() but wanted to understand properly why I can't call the .css method using the [] notation if it still returns an object?

Here is my test code, tried to figure it out myself:

```
$('.slider').each(function() {
  var $slides = $('.slide');

  console.log(jQuery.type($slides.eq(1)));
  console.log(jQuery.type($slides[2]));

  $slides.eq(1).css( {color: 'red'} );
  $slides[2].css( {color: 'red'} );
});
```

console logs tell me that both selectors are returning an object. So why do I get a typeError on the [] notation like it isn't an object?

Appreciate any clarification.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array syntax returns an object but if you want to access JQuery functions on it you will need to call `$(object)` on it, where `.eq()` returns a JQuery object.  For example:

```js
console.log('By eq:', $('button').eq(0).text())
console.log('By Array as a JQuery Object', $( $('button')[0]).text())
try {
  console.log('By Array:', $('button')[0].text())
} catch(e) {
  console.log('You get an exception because the element doens\'t have a  property named text');
  console.log(e);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>A button</button>
```

Comment: also note that "object" is the most generic internal javascript class, and that `jQuery.type` on even a raw HTML element returns `"object"`. In fact, since `$slides[2]` is a raw HTML element, that's exactly what's happening

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I hadn't considered either of your points. 

In my mind, as $slides was a jQuery object it would remain a jQuery object despite using [ ] but now I understand.

Appreciate your time and effort